# Xamarin android c#; Creating a listview in a fragment; Can't use "this"

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, fragment

I am trying to create a ListView in a fragment, but when defining the adapter I need to add the context, but I can't figure out how to do this.

On the internet I read about getActivity() and getContext(), but I can not use these functions. I saw a example which uses @override, a java syntax, but when using "using java:lang", then it complains about the "public" word in the sentence below it.

To summarize my question: how do I use "this" in a fragment in c# in Xamarin Android?

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: You have to extend `ListFragment` to set the `Adapter` via `this`. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)

Comment: Full tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_3_-_specialized_fragment_classes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the `context` is passed into the `Adapter`. So something like..

```
public class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    private Context _context;
    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //....other adapter methods/code
}
```

And then the usage being...

```
// assuming you are in a Fragment
var adapter = new MyAdapter(this.Activity);
```

Since an `Activity` is a context, it's normally passed as a context when needed.

Comment: Only had to type this.Activity indeed! :)